# Firebase strange duplicate update

Tags: firebase

I see a strange behavior using firebase 2.11.2. 
When updating an entry with integer as a key some other entries are updated as well. This was reproduced with simple node code as follows:

```
var fb_ref=new Firebase(...);
fb_ref.authWithCustomToken(db.secret, function(error, authData) {});
//auth passed ... 
var ref=fb_ref.child("/items/315250008"); //there are many items with integers as the keys
var status_ref=ref.child("api/status");
status_ref.update({"foo":"bar"});
```

The result of the above ending update entries 315250008,315250010 (and few more).

Appreciate any help here

Update
Seems that there is connection to the fact these are integers and to their values. It will not happen if the key name is s315250008 or 31525000. 
In addition there is a connection to the number of elements in the array (its not an array but numeric keys might make fb think it is): the exact same scenario will not reproduce on a new branch of the tree.

Comment: When I run the code (minus the auth), I get exactly one node. My Firebase SDK is 2.7 (which is the latest) and Node is 0.10.37. Where did you get that Firebase version number from?

Comment: got it using npm --version firebase , i didnt manage to reproduce it myself using empty node. i suspect that the array behaviuor is somehow relates to that as it happens only with other child nodes and all have high integer keys(that are not serial).

Comment: That 2.11.2 is your npm version, not your Firebase version. To find your Firebase version do `npm ls firebase`. I had a typo before, the latest Firebase JavaScript SDK is 2.**2**.7. But I cannot reproduce the behavior you're describing with the code you posted. If that requires a certain number of nodes to be present, include code to create those nodes. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, That was a stupid mistake. I use 2.02 and now updated to 2.2.7. I do not see the issue now but the system is in a bit different states (dozens of nodes were updating before and not its silent). Thanks for your help, Will update in a day or two that everything is indeed going fine or supply more details on the scenario.

Comment: So updating firebase didnt do the trick but i figured that out ... somewhere else we had clients that wre written in fire-anguar, these clients have implemented 3 way binding and accidentally binded two different entries in the DB through the client. Signs for this issue, it reproduced only on this spesific path, you will see simple update through conolse update two entries but with small delay between the updates. Thanks for your attention